# how to fix the dbx "MT support is disabled" error?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb, solaris, dbx

I loaded a core file of a program which is multi-threaded. I cannot list threads with below command.

```
(dbx) threads
 dbx: MT support is disabled 
(dbx)
```

However, I can list LWPs with lwps. On Solaris, do threads and lwps have a 1-1 mapping?

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris 9 and later, threads are mapped 1:1 to LWP's.  On older releases, it's an M:N mapping.   Much deeper details can be found in [the white paper *Multithreading in the
Solaris™ Operating Environment*](https://blogs.oracle.com/pgdh/resource/pgdh-solaris-threads-paper-v1.1.pdf).

Comment: This is uname -a output. So it is Solaris 5.10? SunOS 5.10 Generic_144489-09 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: also why does dbx say MT support is disabled when I am debugging a multi threaded application

Comment: @Medicine - SunOS 5.10 is Solaris 10.  (For SunOS 5.7 & later, just drop the '5.' to get the Solaris version number.)    I don't know why dbx would say that unless you're using a version that's not supported on Solaris 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the software with the -MT compiler option for "multi-threaded" support.
Recompile (with -MT), generate the core dump and try dbx again.